# Should ShellExecute be used to open default mail program and how can be properly done?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, windows-server-2008-r2, delphi-6

I have found in my company's codebase a code to open default mail program using `ShellExecute`. The code is written long time ago, but I've notice strange behavior on it, the problem only occurs when the debugger is not attached.

```
if ShellExecute(Handle, PChar('open'), PChar('mailto:donotreply@nonono.com'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT) <= 32 then
begin
  //...
end;
```

Above is the relevant part of the code. `Handle` is the Form handle.

To reproduce the problem, simply create a new project, add a button on it and call this code on the button `onClick` event handler. It is also necessary to not have a default mail installed, so windows will display an message warning about that.

When debugging, the message Z order is higher than the application, so the message box is properly displayed and the user can close this message.
When not debugging, the message Z order is lower than the application, so the user has to alt+tab to see that message.

I don't have enough knowledge to understand what is happening nor to state if that behavior is correct or not.

Is there anything I can do to properly display the message box in a higher Z order than my application? 
Is this code deprecated? Should I move forward to a different way of doing this, if so, how?

Comment: What is Handle? ....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Fixed, thank you

Comment: Obvious first question: Is COM properly initialized on the thread that calls [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx)? The reason for the different behavior is likely, that you're calling [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) directly or indirectly. Specifically: *"A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true: [...] The process is being debugged."*

Comment: @IInspectable I've called `CoInitialize(nil)`. What do you mean by 'properly initialized'?

Comment: *"Properly"* as in *"according to the documentation"*. [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) should only be called from a single-threaded apartment (STA) thread. `CoInitialize(nil)` (assuming the call succeeds) initializes the COM library for use by an STA thread.

Comment: ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx are pretty much what you've got available. If it doesn't work to your needs then you've got much room to manoeuvre.

Comment: @IInspectable I wonder what kind of magic is the debugger doing...

Comment: The debugger is implemented in *kernel32.dll*. I doubt there's any magic involved. It's just using its power to make things happen in the same way that it prevents other things from happening.